# Adding BarButtonItems to backButton in view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

i have a view controller, which is standalone and has two left UIBarButtonItem, however when i push it, i want to have these two buttons + the back button

i tried

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // back
    if (self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem) {

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem, self.barButtonFilter, self.barButtonFilterContacts, nil];

    } else {

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.barButtonFilter, self.barButtonFilterContacts, nil];

    }
}
```

if there is a back button, than add, else replace

but i didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to get your problem but according to your caption you want to replace you back button of `UINavigationController` with a bar button item, in that case you simply need to have a custom button in place of back Button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"yourTitle" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(someFunction:)];             
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backButton;   
[backButtonrelease];
```

If this is not your problem please elaborate.

Comment: no i need to have my buttons + the back button, and i dont want to create a custom back button

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here is that a `UINavigationBar` can only have one leftButtonItem and one rightButtonItem. But What you can do is in the center of the `UINavigationBar` you can have a UIView. You can use this to place the buttons on.

Someone has the code here: [adding-buttons-to-the-titleview-of-navigationbar-without-having-to-repeat-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004525/adding-buttons-to-the-titleview-of-navigationbar-without-having-to-repeat-code)

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's iOS Human Interface Guidelines:

> Use a toolbar instead of a navigation bar if you need to offer a
>   larger set of controls, or you do not need to enable navigation.
>
> Avoid crowding a navigation bar with additional controls, even if
>   there appears to be enough space. The navigation bar should contain no
>   more than a view’s current title, the back button, and one control
>   that manages the view’s contents. If, instead, you use a segmented
>   control in the navigation bar, the bar should not display a title and
>   it should not contain any controls other than the segmented control.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html